# How to find which MPIO path is being used for IO?

Tags: windows, networking, storage-area-network, iscsi, mpio

We were experimenting MPIO with our Storage array. We saw the Get-Iscsisession and Get-Iscsiconnection cmdlet to find the paths created. But during IO ,i would like to know which path has been used. Is it possible? Which tool can be used to check that? I am using Windows 2016 as Operating system. We connect to our storage via Iscsi initiator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pathes can be checked in iSCSI GUI (even in the gui-less version of Windows) by using iscsicpl command and then by choosing needed target click "Devices" and "MPIO".

To check the path utilization use Performance Monitor (Listset: ISCSI connection / iSCSI Session) or in powershell smth like:

```
(get-counter -listset "iSCSI Connections")
Get-Counter -Counter "\iSCSI Connections(*)\Bytes Received"
```